# Recursive insert into a tree with 4 children

Tags: python, recursion, insert, tree

I'm trying to construct a tree in Python that can take 4 children. The children are defined as an array. 
What I'm struggling with is inserting recursively into this tree.

Here is what I've done so far:
Node Class:

```
    class node:
         def __init__(self,value,city,children=[None,None,None,None]):
             self.value = value
             self.children = children
             self.city = city
```

Tree Class:

```
from node import *
from isFull import *

class tree:
  root = None

  def __int__(self):
     self.root = None

  def insert(self, city, value):
    if self.root == None:
        self.root = node(value, city, children=[None,None,None,None])

    else:
        self.rec_insert(city, value, self.root, 0)

  def rec_insert(self, city, value, nodes, index):

    if nodes.children[index] is None:
        nodes.children[index] = node(value, city, children=[None,None,None,None])
        return

    elif index < 3:
        self.rec_insert(city, value, nodes, index + 1)

    elif index == 3:
        self.rec_insert(city, value, nodes.children[0], 0)
```

So what I have observed is that this first if statement actually works. I can insert a root and into the first layer of children.

> if nodes.children[index] is None:

Now the problem arises in level 2. Probably because I'm descending wrong. 
At the start I can insert normally into layer 2, however as it gets to the right side of the tree it skips the last child in layer 2.

My logic behind this function:

> self.rec_insert(city, value, nodes.children[0], 0)
>   I wanted to make it descend just into the left most child then my other conditional statements will make it shift right as it inserts.

This check:

> elif index == 3:
>   I use it to determine if all the children have been inserted into in a node.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You indentation does not appear to match what you're actually using.  Please fix it if you want people to take the question seriously.  `__int__` and `insert` and `rec_insert` look like they're intended to be methods of class `tree`, but they are all top-level functions in the code that was posted.

Comment: @TomKarzes I fixed it.

Comment: do you mean `def __init__(self)`?

Comment: As AChampion points out, it looks like `__int__` was intended to be `__init__`

Comment: Ok, here's an observation.  Suppose you've added 5 nodes to the three, i.e. 1 root and 4 immediate children.  Now suppose you want to add a bunch more nodes.  Every single one of those will be added somewhere below `children[0]`, because if the root and all child slots are full, you recurse on the first child.  That may work initially, but your tree will rapidly become unbalanced as you add more nodes to the root.

Comment: Sorry I meant__init__...

Comment: I see that now thanks. But how do I go back up the tree?